# Force users to access SSL site using specific host header

Tags: iis-7, ssl

So i am running IIS7 with one SSL site on it. I have a few different domains and subdomains that all point to my external IP. When using http they all direct to their respective sites using host headers. Whenever someone uses https on any of the domains they all point to my SSL site.

I only want people who type in https://sub.domain.com (for example) to end up at my secure site and for anything else to just not go there, it can throw an error or direct to the http version, it doesn't matter.

Is there a way of getting IIS7 to check the host header and throw an error if it doesn't match my specific subdomain?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use URL Rewrite for that, see Canonicalization and Host Names below:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203210004/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx)

Comment: Nice to see to here Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore [IIS 7.0 Request Filtering and URL Rewriting](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/501/iis-70-request-filtering-and-url-rewriting/)